# How to map the host OS file to the container at the time of container build process

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

docker-compose.yml:

```
    version: '3'
    services:
      ezmove:
        volumes:
          - /host-dir:/home/container-dir    
        build:
          context: .
          args:
            BRANCH: develop
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM appcontainers/ubuntu:xenial

MAINTAINER user <user>

RUN apt-get update -y --no-install-recommends \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python3.5-minimal python3.5-venv \    
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends git \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python-pip \
    && pip install --upgrade pip \  
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && mkdir -p /home/container-dir 

WORKDIR /home/container-dir 

RUN /bin/bash - c "sh ./script.sh"
```

At the **time of build** the docker container How to map local directory to container

When $ docker-compose up, it will starts to build container but after installation of the packag dependancies it will try to execute the script.sh file but got error "FILE NOT FOUND! "

**Tried:**

1. Not want todo git clone inside docker continer
2. Not want to store source code inside the continer

**So, how to map the host OS file to the container at build time**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you lack some `COPY` or `ADD` in your Dockerfile in order to copy your script.sh in your image.

Check the docs

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy

By the way, Docker is about isolation, so a running container should be isolated from the host, and certainly not access the host OS.

Comment: Thanks #user2915097,  Using ADD and COPY its will work but these have limitation like `ADD obeys the following rules:

The <src> path must be inside the context of the build; you cannot ADD ../something /something, because the first step of a docker build is to send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the docker daemon.`

Comment: HI I posted new question related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47067944/how-to-access-the-hosts-machines-localhost-127-0-0-1-from-docker-container/47068162#47068162

Comment: Famous Vonc answered