# How to access the Host's machine's localhost 127.0.0.1 from docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, git-daemon

I hosted Git daemon on local host i.e. `'/usr/bin/git daemon --listen=127.0.0.1 --base-path=/opt'` as a `systemd` service and I am trying to access it from docker container. I didn't mentioned the port because I don't want to expose the port to outside network.

Dockerfile:

```
RUN git clone git://127.0.0.1/repo/ repo_dir
```

But its not working, its looks like inside container its trying to connect localhost of container.

So How to connect connect localhost of Host machine from Docker container?

Comment: ANSWER: Hi guys found solution after reading the docker documentation,      from both side i.e. from Host-to-Container and Contaier-TO-Host we need to map all the ports so for that net to specify the network mode `docker build --network="host"` it will set the networking mode for the RUN instructions during build (default "default"), now from container to host loopback is working file. thanks guys for giving time.  Thanks @VonC

Comment: Good point. I have edited my answer accordingly, with links to the doc and moby releases including that feature.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> its not working, its looks like inside container its trying to connect localhost of container.

Yes, that is the all idea behind the isolation provided by container, even `docker build` (which builds one container per Dockerfile line, and commits it in an intermediate image).

As commented by the [OP dhairya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670520/dhairya), and mentioned in the documentation I referred in my comments: "[Docker container networking](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/)" and [`docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/), you can set to **host** the networking mode for the `RUN` instructions during build: then `localhost` would refer to the host localhost.

```
 docker build --network="host"
```

This is since [API 1.25+ only](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/version-history/#v125-api-changes), in [docker v.1.13.0-rc5](https://github.com/moby/moby/releases/tag/v1.13.0-rc5) (January 2017)

> `POST /build` accepts `networkmode` parameter to specify network used during build.

---

But if you don't need Git in your actual built image (for its main process to run), it would be easier to

- clone the repo locally (directly on the host) *before* the docker build.
  You need to clone it where your Dockerfile is, as it must be relative to the source directory that is being built (the context of the build).
- use a [`COPY` directive](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) in the Dockerfile, to copy the host folder representing the checked out Git repo.
  Note: add `.git/`: to your `.dockerignore` (file in the same folder as your Dockerfile), in order to *not* copy the `repo_dir/.git` folder of that cloned repo, if you don't have git in your target image.

  ```
  COPY repo_dir .
  ```

(Here '`.`' represent the current `WORKDIR` within the image being built)

Comment: Thanks @VonC for reply, I am tring to map the local file system to docker container while building docker container, I also posted similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47030342/how-to-map-the-host-os-file-to-the-container-at-the-time-of-container-build-proc , So I came up with the local git daemon checkout but still I am not able to map the host machines file inside docker while build, SO I have only option like ADD and COPY but they have limitations as you mentioned above i.e 'file need to be inside docker context dir'.

Comment: So is there any alternative for this case ?

Comment: @Dhairya Yes: simply clone your git repo within the context folder of your build.

Comment: Hi @VonC I am new to docker and I have a query: when 2 docker containers are communicating with each other, the docker bridge 'docker0' will do the port forwarding in between two docker container, so suppose I hosted service like git-daemon on host machine on port 9418, how we can access these service from docker container?

Comment: @Dhairya My point is: you don't need tow containers: just one where you copy your repo content.

Comment: @Dhairya a docker daemon on the host machine is not visible by any containers. You could create a second container mounting the repo, and hosting a docker daemon, then visible by your first container (https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/)... but this seems overkill. Simple COPY and move on.

Comment: For me network_mode: "bridge" worked better with the port forwarding see