# Docker not loading files from npm run serve

Tags: docker, npm

I have a development environment where I run `npm run serve` in my local terminal and then `docker-compose up -d` in a different terminal to run the services I need to start my system.

I have an instance where I am attempting to run front-end tests, which I run inside of a running container using nightwatchJS, and for some reason the test runner is not accessing the files loaded from `npm run serve`. Quite literally when I print out a screenshot using the test runner the page looks as if I have canceled running `npm run serve`, however when I go to the page `127.0.0.1` in my browser, everything is loading as usual.

I think my issue is that the test is being run inside of a docker container like so:

`docker-compose exec web bash -c "npx nightwatch ...file"`

where that specific instance is not running `npm run serve` but I am confused as to why it works when I hit the browser personally. I have tried exposing ports in the Dockerfile but that does not work.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8.5-slim-buster

# the first 2 prevent Python from writing out pyc files or from buffering stdin/stdout
# the others are Node
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV NVM_DIR /usr/local/nvm
ENV NODE_VERSION 12.7.0
ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH

# the man1 directory is not present for slim-buster so we add that and then install all of the default system based dependencies
# NOTE...TOP LAYERS ARE CACHED FIRST!!!!
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1 \
    && apt-get clean && apt-get update -y && apt-get install pdftk-java curl git -y \
    && curl --silent -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.2/install.sh | bash \
    && apt-get install zlib1g-dev libjpeg-dev python3-pythonmagick inkscape xvfb poppler-utils libfile-mimeinfo-perl qpdf libimage-exiftool-perl ufraw-batch ffmpeg gcc procps -y \
    && apt-get clean && apt-get autoclean

# SELINUM
# get wget...
# Adding trusting keys to apt for repositories
RUN apt-get install gnupg -y && apt-get install wget -y \
    && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list' \
    && apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install google-chrome-stable -y \
    && apt-get install unzip -yqq

# Set up Chromedriver Env Vars
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION 87.0.4280.20
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_DIR /chromedriver
# make directory for it...
RUN mkdir $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR

# Download and install Chromedriver
RUN wget -q --continue -P $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR "http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip" \
&& unzip $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR/chromedriver* -d $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR \
&& rm "$CHROMEDRIVER_DIR/chromedriver_linux64.zip"

# Put Chromedriver into the PATH
ENV PATH $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR:$PATH
# Set display port as an environment variable
ENV DISPLAY=:99
# SELINUM
## NIGHTMARE
#RUN apt-get install wget -y && wget http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.44/selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -P /bin/
#RUN apt install default-jre -y
#RUN apt-get install -y xvfb x11-xkb-utils xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-scalable xfonts-cyrillic x11-apps clang libdbus-1-dev libgtk2.0-dev libnotify-dev libgconf2-dev libasound2-dev libcap-dev libcups2-dev libxtst-dev libxss1 libnss3-dev gcc-multilib g++-multilib


# ensure node is installed, and at the end, make the working directory
RUN . $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm use default \
    && mkdir /code

# set working directory to /code...it was just made for this purpose
WORKDIR /code
# possible that these will cache so separate them from COPY . /code/
COPY requirements.txt /code/
# now install, this will normally also cache

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
# place this at the end because the code will always change...this will almost never cache...
COPY . /code/

EXPOSE 8001
EXPOSE 8888
```

Here is my compose file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379"
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      main:
        aliases:
          - redis

  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file: ./.env
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      main:
        aliases:
          - postgres

  #access by going to localhost:16543
  #when adding a server to the serve list
  #the hostname is postgres
  #the username is postgres
  #the password is postgres
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    links:
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    env_file: ./.env
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "16543:80"
    networks:
      main:
        aliases:
          - pgadmin


  celery:
    build:
      network: host
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev    # use docker-dev because production npm installs and npm builds
    command: python manage.py celery
    env_file: ./.env
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - tmp:/tmp
    links:
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - redis
    networks:
      main:
        aliases:
          - celery

  web:
    build:
      network: host
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - tmp:/tmp
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file: ./.env
    restart: unless-stopped
    links:
      - postgres
      - redis
      - celery
      - pgadmin
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
      - celery
      - pgadmin
    networks:
      main:
        aliases:
          - web

volumes:
  pgdata:
  tmp:

networks:
  main:
```

Comment: Might be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47067944/how-to-access-the-hosts-machines-localhost-127-0-0-1-from-docker-container

Comment: This is not resolve my issue and I attempted using `network:host` as well as shown here: https://forums.docker.com/t/option-network-mode-host-in-docker-compose-file-not-working-as-expected/51682/2