# Docker containers not able to communicate to each other

Tags: django, postgresql, docker-compose

I'm trying to prepare a docker-compose.yml file to serve a django app.
I have two services:

1. the web server (using gunicorn)
2. the database (Postgres)

this is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
      - POSTGRES_DB=db_name
      - POSTGRES_USER=admin
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
    networks:
      main:
        aliases:
          - postgres
  web:
    image: django-app:latest
    build:
      network: host
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    links:
      - postgres
    networks:
      main:
        aliases:
          - web
volumes:
  postgres_data:
networks:
  main:
```

My Dockerfile file:

```
# Use the official Python image as a base image
FROM python:3.11-slim-buster

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV BUD_DATABASE_HOST postgres
ENV BUD_DATABASE_PORT 5432
ENV BUD_DATABASE_NAME db_name
ENV BUD_DATABASE_USER admin
ENV BUD_DATABASE_PASSWORD admin
ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE budenje.settings.dev

# Instalación de paquetes adicionales
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    postgresql-client build-essential libpq-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the Django project files
COPY . .

# Run migrations and collect static files
RUN python manage.py migrate
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

# Start the Django development server

CMD ["gunicorn", "budenje.wsgi:application", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

And app/settings/dev.py file:

```
from app.settings.base import *
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

EMAIL_HOST= 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT= 1025

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'PORT': os.environ.get('BUD_DATABASE_PORT', '5432'),
        'NAME': os.environ.get('BUD_DATABASE_NAME', 'db'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('BUD_DATABASE_USER', 'adming'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('BUD_DATABASE_PASSWORD', 'admin'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('BUD_DATABASE_HOST', 'localhost'),
    }
}
```

What I receive is:

`0.977 django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known`

I tried setting docker networks in several ways, fixed IP result o timeout instead of connection refused.

I am spinning up the db service before the web service, connecting to the db service by console with no problem.

I don't know what else to do. I had several times this kind of issue with docker services.

Comment: Are you sure your postgres service is actually ready? If not, https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/ if that isn't the issue, I'd add your services to the same network

Comment: Yes, I did `psql -d app -h localhost -p 5433 -U admin -W` and successfully connected to the docker container from local console

Comment: I'm not available to run code. I'd suggest looking at my post here, I show more-or-less my dev compose file that accomplishes what you are looking for connection-wise: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66459609/8382028

Comment: `django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known`

I added the network aliases like you did in the code shared and also added `network: host` inside build: in web service

Answer (score 0):

In your docker-compose.yml:

```
container_name: db
```

Mismatch with ENV variable:

```
ENV BUD_DATABASE_HOST postgresql.test
```

Change ENV variable to:

```
ENV BUD_DATABASE_HOST db
```

Comment: I henningb, I just updated the docker files after adding the changes suggested by ViaTech

Comment: Yes that's works as well, as long as you use the same address it will work; db or postgres.